# How Does The Visual Studio Code Integrated Terminal Work in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am running Visual Studio Code Version 1.19.3 on Linux Mint 18.3.  When I try to execute binaries that I can clearly see and run in my external terminal, they cannot be found.  When I 'ls' /usr/bin from the integrated terminal, many files are missing and others are different versions.

External bash /usr/bin ls snippet:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         10392 Jan 30  2016 pgmtolispm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         17048 Jan 30  2016 pgmtopbm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         10392 Jan 30  2016 pgmtoppm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         27280 Nov 21  2016 pgrep
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root            22 Jan 15 21:29 phar -> /etc/alternatives/phar
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root            12 Aug  9 10:43 phar7.0 -> phar.phar7.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root            27 Jan 15 21:29 phar.phar -> /etc/alternatives/phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         14826 Aug  9 10:42 phar.phar7.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root            21 Jan 15 21:29 php -> /etc/alternatives/php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root       4430896 Aug  9 10:43 php7.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root          6264 Jan 30  2016 pi1toppm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         10384 Jan 30  2016 pi3topbm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        200736 Jan 29  2016 pic
```

Integrated terminal /usr/bin ls snippet:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   3 nfsnobody nfsnobody   45393 Dec 31  1969 perlthanks
-rwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody   14408 Dec 31  1969 pfbtops
-rwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody   38896 Dec 31  1969 pg
-rwxr-xr-x   3 nfsnobody nfsnobody   26680 Dec 31  1969 pgrep
-rwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody  200696 Dec 31  1969 pic
```

Is VSC creating some kind of virtual filesystem for the terminal that has its own /usr/bin, but still attaches my working folder in the right path?  I am lost and it is preventing me from being able to use the Google debugger and PHP Intellisense, just to name a couple of things.

Comment: I have a resolution, but little new understanding.  My original install was made from the software store.  It installed a flatpack version of the application.  This appears to jailed, somehow, to a virtual filesystem.  I uninstalled it, downloaded the dpkg from the git site, and installed that.  Now the integrated terminal is running in the same space as my external shell.  I'll leave the question open because the phenomenon is woefully under-documented.